# Expression to describe 'making a final effort'

Tags: expressions, idioms

I wonder if there is an idiom for this sentence: "After so much work, you must make a final effort." or "You got this far, just another step"
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

"After so much work, just keep it up a little longer!"

"You've got this far, just make the final push!"

Comment: @Franci that was Enguroo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

The **eleventh hour** is nigh, just keep it up a little longer.

> Definition of eleventh hour:    the latest possible time before it is
>   too late
>
> ```
> still making changes at the eleventh hour
>
> [Merriam Webster][1]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> After so much work, you must ***finish it off***.
>   You got this far,
>   just ***finish it off***

TFD(idioms):

> [**finish off**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/finish+it+off) (redirected from **finish it off**)
>
> 1. To finish the last part of something. A noun or pronoun can be used between "finish" and "off."
>      Printing is the last step in finishing
>      off this project, thank goodness.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

***in the home stretch***

This is a term that comes from horse racing, identifying the last straight part of the race course before the finish line.  Traditionally, the jockeys work their horses the hardest in the home stretch, getting them to put in the most effort to get or stay ahead of the other horses, and hopefully win.

[image: home stretch]
*([Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Home_stretch,_Havre_de_Grace_Race_Track,_Havre_de_Grace,_Md_(63143).jpg))*

It's come to mean the last part of any long and arduous task. The anticipation of getting past a task you've struggled with, and seeing it well done, is an inducement to putting in the final effort.

You'll find many definitions online, such as the one at [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/home-stretch):

> the last part of a race or other activity:
>
> *We’ve been on this project for three months, but we’re in the home stretch now.*

Comment: I've started a discussion on Wikimedia Commons questioning whether the photo is really public domain as claimed. I guess I'll have to remove it if necessary, but _(sigh)_ it's _soo perfect_.